# How to get size of screen with videoinput in openCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm doing face detection with OpenCV and I need to get coordinate of the face location on the screen. How to get it with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that you have not gone through any other content yet, I would first suggest doing some reseach on the same.

Reference 1: [Haar Cascades](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html),
Reference 2: [Dlib](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/03/facial-landmarks-dlib-opencv-python/), Reference 3: [Face Recognition](https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)

The following code will help you with the haar cascades method for face detection.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# the xml files are present in the data folder of the opencv installation, should load automatically.
# You can download the xml from:
# https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    print (x, y, w, h) #Print location of the face => x co-ord, y co-ord, width and height
```